# Image map coordinates for responsive images in bootstrap not working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, imagemap

Index.html

```
    <div class="carousel-inner" >
<div class="item active" data-slide-number="0">
        <img src="resources/images/banners1.png" border="0" usemap="#Map"  class="fill img-responsive">
        <map name="Map">
                <area shape="rect" style="outline:none;" coords="150,209,298,317" id="slidepopup" href="#" />
                <area shape="rect" style="outline:none;" coords="324,209,473,315" href="requestDemo.html" />
                <area shape="rect" style="outline:none;" coords="500,210,648,314" href="downloadtrailversion.html" />
                <area shape="rect" style="outline:none;" coords="557,416,696,466" href="banner1content.html" />
        </map>

</div>

 <div class="item" data-slide-number="1"> 
                 <img src="resources/images/banners2.png" border="0" usemap="#Map2" class="fill img-responsive">
                  <map name="Map2">
                      <area shape="rect" style="outline:none;" coords="557,416,696,466" href="platformoncloud.html" />
                 </map>
</div>

 <div class="item" data-slide-number="2">
               <img src="resources/images/banners3.png"  border="0" usemap="#Map3" class="fill img-responsive"/>
               <map name="Map3"><area shape="rect" style="outline:none;" coords="462,394,601,433" href="visualanalytics.html" /></map>

 </div>

</div>
```

Jquery:

https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps

Jquery method call:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
});
```

In the above code responsive image map links were not working..so i used some plugin, so it got worked for me for the first image(banners1.png) in desktop,iPAD,mobile. but for second(banners2.png) and third image(banners2.png) link is not at all working.if i remove the plugins links are working fine but not in all devices..does anyone know whats the solution for this??thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been almost 8 years since this question has been asked, but I'll still answer it.

You can do something like this:

The first one:

```
<img class="contact-background-image" src="" usemap="#image-map"
```

The second one:

```
<img class="d3-image-default" src="" usemap="#d3-image-map"
```

And for the first tag, use jQuery like so:

```
('.contact-background-image').rwdImageMaps();
```

And for the second tag, Use jQuery like so:

```
('.d3-image-default').rwdImageMaps();
```

As is stated in [issue 64](https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps/issues/64#issuecomment-511904906) of the jQuery-rwdImageMaps Github repository.

Hope this helps anyone who may still come across this problem in the future.